# Swagger with Service Stack not working

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger

I am trying to implement Swagger with Service Stack. I've installed service stack with swagger using nuget. Current DLL versions are reported as 3.9.56.0 mostly.

I am trying to follow the example provided at...
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/SwaggerHelloWorld

and the instrucstion appear fairly fool-proof...

```
Plugins.Add(new ServiceStack.Api.Swagger.SwaggerFeature());
```

goes into the 'Configure' method after I've installed via nuget (as the documentation instructs), then I've added [ApiMember] and [Api] tags, along with changes to the [Route] tags to add Summary and Notes

but when I visit `~/swagger-ui/index.html` i get the error

```
Please specify the protocol for ../api
```

My api sits at `~/api`, and I have a single method at the moment (Hello World) sitting at `~api/Hello/{name}` which returns JSON and works ok.

if I visit `~api`i get the message `Handler for Request not found:` with a stack trace type output.

What am I doing wrong? The instructions to enable swagger appear really straight forward, and detailed instructions appear to be lacking, probably because it should 'just work', please help!

Update to address Esker...

Stack trace @ myhost:54011/api

```
Handler for Request not found: 


Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /api
Request.FilePath: /api
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.MapPath('~'): D:\Starteam\Private\user\web\ServiceStackSwagger\ServiceStackSwagger\
Request.Path: /api
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /api
Request.PhysicalPath: D:\Starteam\Private\user\web\ServiceStackSwagger\ServiceStackSwagger\api
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: D:\Starteam\Private\user\web\ServiceStackSwagger\ServiceStackSwagger\
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /api
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://localhost:54011/api
Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /api
Request.Url.Fragment: 
Request.Url.Host: localhost
Request.Url.LocalPath: /api
Request.Url.Port: 54011
Request.Url.Query: 
Request.Url.Scheme: http
Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: D:\Starteam\Private\user\web\ServiceStackSwagger\ServiceStackSwagger
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [global.asax,global.asax.cs,helloservice.cs,jquery-1.10.2.js,packages.config,servicestackswagger.csproj,servicestackswagger.csproj.user,web.config,web.debug.config,web.release.config,app_data,app_start,bin,controllers,dto,models,obj,properties,swagger-ui,views]
App.DefaultHandler: metadata
App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/api|D:\Starteam\Private\user\web\ServiceStackSwagger\ServiceStackSwagger\api
```

Also, "Please specify protocol' is a swagger error, displayed onscreen in html underneath the aforementioned 'textbox to change discovery url'

and the DLL versions are 'mostly' the same because ServiceStack.Redis is version 3.9.57.0, but I'm not using that, so 'mostly'

Update... My Solution

I needed this in my web.config file inside of the `<configuration>` tag, I had previously not included the `<location path="api">` bit.

```
<!-- ServiceStack: CustomPath /api -->
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

also... I had set up my 'routes' as such...

```
//INCORRECT
[Route("/api/Hello/{name}", Summary = @"N031'5 ServiceStackSwagger thingy", Notes = "Some more info in here cause these are notes")]    
    public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
```

but that messed with swagger's functionality, it needed to be...

```
//CORRECT   
[Route("/Hello/{name}"...
```

with the 'api' bit REMOVED, and now everything is working.

Comment: What's the value you have set for `discoveryUrl` in the `window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi....` initialization script in your index.html file?

Comment: I'm using `../api`, but I've also got a text box onscreen to change that value and make another attempt. @esker

Comment: Can you show the stack trace for that "Handler for Request not found" error? Also, that "Please specify the protocol" - how exactly does that error appear, any idea about where that error come from? Does it seem to be a Javascript error, etc.

Comment: Also, you say "Current DLL versions are reported as 3.9.56.0 *mostly*". If some of your ServiceStack assembly references are not exactly the same version number, there can be problems.

Comment: thanks @esker i've added an update to answer your queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Swagger about the specific URL of the ServiceStack Swagger endpoint, rather than the base URL of your services. This endpoint is located at `/resources` under your base URL. So, instead of `../api` for the `discoveryUrl`, use `../api/resources`, like so, in your index.html file:

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    discoveryUrl: '../api/resources',
    ...
```

Comment: Nope, that hasn't helped. "Please specify the protocol for ../api/resources" is now the message.