# Swagger not able to retrieve operations from ServiceStack resources Service

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to get Swagger to work with ServiceStack. The web server is located behind a Firewall and accessed from the Internet (my.domain.de:80). Requests are then forwarded to the web server on Port 8070.

When visiting the swagger page it is able to access `/api/resources` and retrieve the List of ServiceMethods, but then fails to retrieve the List of Operations.

When I use fiddler to inspect the result I see that he `/api` is missing so that swagger tries to get the List of Operations from `/resources/ServiceName` instead of `/api/resources/ServiceName`.

The Swagger-UI gives me the following error message:

> Unable to read api 'ServiceName' from path http://my.domain.de/resource/ServiceName (server returned Not Found)

SwaggerConfig:

```
discoveryUrl:"../../api/resources",
```

ServiceStack Config:

```
WebHostUrl = "http://my.domain.de"
```

**Update(2)**
If I dont set the WebHostUrl the BasePath in the initial response from ServiceStacks resources service contains the portnumber from the webserver `basePath=http://my.domain.de:8060/api`. But on the Firewall this port is not reachable, nor do we want it to be reachable.

`web.config`:

```
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

**Update**

in the Inital response the basepath is:

```
basePath=http://my.domain.de
```

and by my.domain.de I mean a real world url which is just the hostname without port, url-path, querystring or fragment (I acctually checked wikipedia for the correct names ;)

I have found this other question on StackOverflow, but it did not help me.
[Swagger with Service Stack not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150351/swagger-with-service-stack-not-working)

How can I get ServiceStack/Resources Service to either add `/api` for its returned ServiceList?

Comment: What's the value of `basePath` in the response of the initial `/api/resources` request?

Comment: Are you actually setting the `WebHostUrl` config value to something specific, or are you just showing us what the value of that config is in your original post?

Comment: @esker updated to answer your questions

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're setting the value of the `WebHostUrl` config property? With a typical setup, it isn't necessary to set that config. I think this is what's causing problems.

Comment: @esker updated to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Colleague of op here.

I spent some time researching this problem and I believe the issue is a bug in ServiceStack's swagger support.

See here:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/800

Quote:"When set, use webhosturl for base url in swagger and metadata links"

It is implemented correctly for metadata, but not for swagger.

Line 52 in SwaggerResourcesService.cs overrides the baseurl with the WebHostUrl if it is set, but does not combine with the real path as the implementation in metadata does:

https://github.com/sneal/ServiceStack/blob/6b33f5c2417587b5983c611b4bf8a5d42d88d890/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerResourcesService.cs